# How to avoid resetting a value by pressing a button again

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The `buttonGuess` runs `numRandom` function when it's pressed and it also runs `remainingAttemps` function. The problem is if user presses the `buttonGues`, `Attemps` value is reasigned again.

```
import tkinter
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')

x = random.randint(1,10)
remainingTime = True
Attempts = 4

def countdown (time_left):
    global remainingTime
    if remainingTime == True:
        lblCrono.configure(text = str(time_left))
        if time_left > 0:
            time_left = time_left - 1
            window.after(1000, countdown, time_left)
        else:
            remainingTime = False
            lblCrono.configure(text = 0)
            return remainingTime, gameOver()
    else:
        return

def numRamdom():
    global Attempts
    numWritten = int(entryWriteNumber.get())
    if numWritten > x:
        lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a smaller number')
        return remainingAttempts(Attempts)
    if numWritten < x:
        lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a bigger number')
        return remainingAttempts(Attempts)
    if numWritten == x:
        lblClue.configure(text = 'Congratulations ;)')
        remainingTime = False
        return remainingTime, countdown(0)

def gameOver():
    if remainingTime == False and Attempts != 0:
        lblClue.configure(text = '¡Time\'s up!')
    else:
        lblClue.configure(text = 'No attempts')

def remainingAttempts(countAtempts):
    Attempts = countAtempts
    if Attempts == 0:
        return remainingTime, countdown(0), Attempts, gameOver()
    else:
        Attempts = Attempts - 1

entryWriteNumber = tkinter.Entry(window)
entryWriteNumber.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

lblNumber = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Number', font = 'Comic 13 bold')
lblNumber.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.W )

buttonGuess = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Guess', bg = 'light grey', padx = 20, command = numRamdom)
buttonGuess.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = tkinter.W, padx = 10, pady = 10)

lblClue = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Clue', font = 'Comic 13 bold')
lblClue.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = tkinter.W )

lblCrono = tkinter.Label(window, text = '', bg = 'white', fg = 'red', font = 'Comic 20', padx = 50, pady = 5)
lblCrono.grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = tkinter.S, padx = 100, pady = 150)


countdown(30)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is pressed again?

Comment: So when you press the button and don't get the number right, decrease Attempt. But when numRandom is called, Attempts is reasigned again (At least I think this is what happens)

Comment: I don't think that is what is going on because `numRamdom()` isn't changing `Attempts` — nor is `remainingAttempts()`.

Comment: Adter looking at your code some more, I see several errors, some possibly related to the problem but not all. While it might be possible to fix things it would be a lot of work. I suggest you start over and define your game as a Python `class`. This will get rid of most of the global variables (which are likely the root cause of the problem). Also if you're going to write Python code, I suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all much easier to manage when you get rid of everything that either isn't doing anything or is unnecessary. All your `returns` are doing nothing. Creating a `remainingTime` variable when you have a counter is unnecessary. Giving your widgets and functions a bunch of complicated and/or misleading names, isn't helping. You were calling `countdown(0)` which calls `gameOver()` and then calling `gameOver()`.

You never put something on `row=4`, but you put your timer on `row=5`. This is visibly no different than putting it on 4. You had very repetitive `grid` `options` so I homogenized them in a `dict` and used that `dict` as `**kwargs`. Writing your arguments like this -> `func(arg1 = value1, arg2 = value2, ...)` has no benefit. There's no reason to keep a reference to `lblNumber` or `buttonGuess`. You never modify or further reference either, in any way. If you don't specify a `column`, `tkinter` will assume you mean `column=0`. If you don't specify a `row`, `tkinter` will assume you mean 1 row greater than the total current rows, regardless of column. Importing `tkinter` without an alias just gives you more to type.

Below is my edit of your game based on everything I just wrote.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x500')

x = random.randint(1,10)
remaining = 4

def countdown(time_left):
    global process
    chrono['text'] = str(time_left)
    if time_left:
        process = root.after(1000, countdown, time_left-1)
    else:
        gameOver()

def check():
    global remaining
    
    n = int(guess.get())
    if n == x:
        gameOver(True)
        return
    else:
        clue['text'] = f'Its a {"smaller" if n > x else "bigger"} number'
        
    remaining -= 1
    if not remaining:
        gameOver()

def gameOver(win=False):
    root.after_cancel(process)
    if not win:
        clue['text'] = '¡Time\'s up!' if remaining else 'No attempts remain'
    else:
        clue['text'] = 'Congratulations ;)'


grid = dict(padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Label(root, text='Number', font='Comic 13 bold').grid(**grid)

guess = tk.Entry(root)
guess.grid(**grid)

tk.Button(root, text='Guess', bg='light grey', padx=20, command=check).grid(**grid)

clue = tk.Label(root, text='Clue', font='Comic 13 bold', width=20, anchor='w')
clue.grid(**grid)

chrono = tk.Label(root, text='', bg='white', fg='red', font='Comic 20', padx=50, pady=5)
chrono.grid(column=1, **grid)

countdown(30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I didn't know about `**kwargs`. My actual knowledge of Python doesn't understand some things about the code written: why you use `global remaining` and `global process` if your in the same function? `if not remaining` refers when remaining attempts are 0? There can't be '-1 attempts' ? Why you have written `if time_left` ? There is always going to be an argument in that function, otherwise you couldn't call that function, could you? Anyway, thank you very much. I will try to understand the code and improve it.

Comment: @KIRA ~ `global remaining` refers to the global variable `remaining=4`. If you don't specify `global` there it throws an error referring to it being `local`. `process` is also used in `gameOver`. If something equals `0`, `False` or `None` then it is `not` otherwise it "is" There is no need to check if something is `0` specifically. `remaining -= 1` subtracts 1 from whatever `remaining` is at that time.